# Determinant of matrix with character elements in R

Tags: r, matrix, character, element, determinants

I have the following code:

```
x1 <- c("x", "y")
x2 <- c("z", "w")
X <-data.frame(x1,x2)
A=as.matrix(X)
```

The matrix `A` is the following:

```
      x1  x2 
[1,] "x" "z"
[2,] "y" "w"
```

How can I find the determinant of `A`? I want a result like `xw-yz`.

I tried `det(A)` but it does not work.

In general, I want to be able to find the determinant of any matrix whose elements are of character type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **giacR** package:

```r
library(giacR)

giac <- Giac$new()

command <- "det([[x, y], [z, w]])"
giac$execute(command)
# [1] "x*w-y*z"

giac$close()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a symbolic computation library:

```
library(rSymPy)

x1 <- List(Var("x"), Var("y"))
x2 <- List(Var("z"), Var("w"))
A = Matrix(x1, x2)
Det <- function(x) Sym("(", x, ").det()")
Det(A)
# [1] "w*x - y*z"

x <- Var("x") 
y <- Var("y") 
z <- Var("z")
A = Matrix(List(y+z,z,y), List(z,z+x,x), List(y,x,x+y))
Det(A)
# [1] "4*x*y*z"

a <- Var("a") 
b <- Var("b") 
c <- Var("c")
A = Matrix(List(0,b-a,c-a), List(a-b,0,c-b), List(a-c,b-c,0))
Det(A)
# [1] "0"
```

Comment: the package `rSymPy` is not available in R 3.5.1.
However, in CRAN I found that it does not have specific requirements.

Comment: you can download the compressed source and install from here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/index.html